# HttpClient returns html from API

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Trying to use the HttpClient to get a json response from an API but keep getting html response. In the browser and in Postman I get the result in json just by typing in the url. When using RestSharp I also get the response in json. What do I need to add to get the response in json? The variable responseString in a html string, not a json string.

I use .net core 3.1.

Here's the code:

```
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var response = await GetResponse();
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetResponse()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/");

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept",
            "application/json");

        using var response = await client.GetAsync((
            "/artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups"));

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the `responseString` is a valid json string in some online json parser. If yes you are not getting html. You need to deserialize it into concrete object

Comment: Edited the question clarified that the response is in html, not in json.

Comment: Can you share the HTML response?

Comment: can you use `WebClient` class instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the API is looking for a User-Agent.

Try to Add

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36")
```

Comment: it worked for me, also remove the first slash on client.GetAsync((`"artist/5b11f4ce-a62d-471e-81fc-a69a8278c7da?fmt=json&inc=url-rels+release-groups"`))

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, you might want to consider declaring your `HttpClient` as static. It is recommended in [its documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#remarks). Also if you want json, you need to use [`DeserializeObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) method:

```cs
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(responseString);
```

You just need to make sure that you have already installed the `Newtonsoft.Json` from Nuget packages and also added the following to your `using` directives:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution I had was that somewhere in my address there was an unintended double-slash, removing it returned the requested type as per the Accept header.

In this case I had a set a baseurl which ended in a slash ("someapi.com/integration/") and started the url passed into my Get method with a slash ("/somerequest"). This then became just the domain ("someapi.com" with no subdirectory "/integration") followed by the rest of the url supplied in my Get method (so "someapi.com/somerequest") when submitted using HttpClient, and led to me getting html back instead of json because I was now requesting a web page.

tldr: Typo double-slash in the url gave me the wrong response